# How to add appArmor to linux distributions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, config, nanopi

I am trying to add appArrmor to my [img](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Building_U-boot_and_Linux_for_H5/H3/H2%2B) ([instructions](https://github.com/friendlyarm/sd-fuse_h3)).

[This is](https://github.com/friendlyarm/linux/blob/sunxi-4.11.y/arch/arm/configs/sunxi_defconfig) the .config file that my device use.

I have add `CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR=y` `CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR_HASH=y` `CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR_HASH_DEFAULT=y` `CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR_BOOTPARAM_VALUE=1` but `sudo apparmor_status` still return
`apparmor module is not loaded.`

I have too questions

1. Is there a way to show all the .config on the running machine to know if appArmor is indeed included.
2. Are there other things that I need to set in order to make appArmor work.

Comment: How did you "add" those values precisely? Did you do it correctly through one of the various targets `make config/nconfig/menuconfig/...`, or did you directly edit the file yourself?

Comment: I have changed the file directly and than executed this (https://github.com/friendlyarm/sd-fuse_h3/blob/master/build-kernel.sh) file before compiling the ISO

Comment: You should not modify the config file by hand, there's a good chance of messing things up. If some options have other dependencies your changes are not going to work, if some options are mutually exclusive you can end up breaking something, etc. You should use `make menuconfig` to do it.